# Pub/Sub Communication between twincat3 and azure

Tags: stl, azure-sql-database, azure-iot-hub, plc, twincat

I am new in this field. My condition is, I have a Beckhoff PLC using Twincat3 software. I am using OPC UA to upload data to OPC UA server and then send data to the cloud (Azure SQL database) through Azure IoT Hub. I wanted to make a pub/sub communication. The next steps, I will analyze the data with power bi and display it on several power bi mobile with different types of information. The problem is I have a bit confusion about how Pub/Sub communication applied in this connection. I have read about MQTT and AMPQ but do I need to write a code to be able to apply Pub/Sub communication? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Azure IoT Hub is a Pub/Sub service.  You can subscribe multiple stream processors to the data that hits the hub, and each one will see the entire stream.  These stream processors can be implemented in custom code, perhaps with an [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/functions-js-iot-hub-processing/), but also with [Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-monitoring-notifications-with-azure-logic-apps) or [Azure Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs#create-an-iot-hub-data-stream-input).

Answer (score 0):

You can set up OPC UA servers at both the PLC and the cloud. Each can subscribe to objects on the other for two way exchange. Otherwise, make the OPCUA objects available on the PLC, the subscribe to then from your cloud service.

Of course you will need to enable all the necessary ports and handle certificate exchange.

If you are using the Beckhoff OPC UA server, you annotate the required variables / structs with attributes. See the documentation.

If you want to use MQTT, instead you will need to write some code, using the MQTT library for TwinCAT. You will also need to get your broker set up and again, handle security. There are decent examples for the main providers Inthe Beckhoff documentation for the MQTT library.